# how to animate UILabel in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to animate UILabel in form of news read ...ex:-  How are you is my UILabel . I want it to move to left and loop once the last word is moved complete left. 
If anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

Take a look at [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)'s animation methods, such as `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`. You can animate the view's `frame`, and using the completion handler you can call another method to move the view back.

Essentially, think of the `animate` method as going one way, and the completion handler as going the other way. Call the entire thing on a timer/loop, and you'll have it going continuously back and forth

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    label.frame = frame;
}];
```

'frame' should be the new frame of the label. You can use this method to animate changes on all UIKit views.

Answer (score 0):

Please do some basics before ask question.

Anyway, there are two common ways to achieve that.

- Using ***animateWithDuration:animations:completion:***, by which you add the label to the view and animate through a time by setting the destination frame in ***animation:*** block.Like:

  ```
  //set initial frame for the label and add to the self.view
  [UIView animateWithDuration:/*animation duration*/ animations:^{
      //set destination frame of the label, only change x-axis value
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }];
  ```
- Or you can use ***NSTimer*** if you want a continuous loop of this animation. For example:

  ```
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:/*label_change_time*/ target:nil selector:@selector(moveLabelToLeft:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  ```

and in the ***moveLabelToLeft:*** set the difference of x-axis value over the label_change_time